# Formatting read-only usb with badblocks

Tags: usb, mount, read-only, badblocks

I have a usb stick that suddenly started mounting read-only. I was going try and reformat it (e.g. with `gparted`) but wouldn't let me as it's mounted read only. Also (optimistically) tried zero-ing it (i.e. `dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sdb` - again same problem).

Tried some of the regular fixes to mounting usb problems ... e.g:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/mountpoint
mount: cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected
```

Tried `sudo dosfsck -a /dev/sdb1` - (it was a fat32 formatted USB stick), with similar effect. Also ran `badblocks`, which found 25 bad blocks.

Any clues on what's going on? And what else I can try?

Comment: This problem (and/or related problems) is described at the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/help-me-i-cant-format-my-usb-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: Damn (and thanks) .... sounds like it's 'gridlocked'. On the plus side, I learned a new term.  Will poke around and hope for the best.

Comment: Please try according to the list in the link in my previous comment, ' The drive is read-only:'. Chances are that it is gridlocked, but maybe something is disturbing the function, and you might be able to work around it. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the price of USB flash drives what it is, compared with the value of whatever you're likely to store on it, the best thing I can suggest for a flash drive with bad blocks is to toss it in the trash (erase with a hammer first, if you're concerned about data that might be recoverable from the drive) and buy a new one.

Comment: ...It is a 256 GB though -  would prefer not to (I think it was circa $200). But yeah, otherwise I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I have only one thing to say about $200 USB sticks:  O.o